# Book Identification: Blue Runes and Talking Horses

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book that I began reading years ago but never finished.

It involved a girl (I think her name started with an "A") who escaped through a doorway into a fantasy world. I believe she used some sort of a blue talisman to get through, and she meets a talking mare who has a colt.

There was something about runes in the world; blue were good, but red were bad. I believe the talking mare was almost on the evil side. That's basically as far as I got in the book. Does anybody know what I'm talking about? I think there was something about wolves as well. They were chasing the girl as she traveled with the horse.